# Boolean operator precedence

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I have question about Python operator precedence.

```
print(not (8 < 4) or (10 == 5 * 2) and not (5 > 3))
```

The above code prints 'True'. But I think the result is 'False', with the following steps:

```
>>print(not F or T and not T)
>>print(T or T and F)
>>print(T and F)
>>print(F)
```

So I don't know why the result is 'True'
Maybe I'm missing the small detail.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence - `and` beats `or`

Comment: Please retake the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you have a question about operator precedence, we expect you to research the documentation and existing questions, before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

`and` has higher precedence than `or`.

```
>>print(not F or T and not T)
>>print(T or T and F)
>>print(T or (T and F))       # Evaluated like this.
>>print(T or F)
>>print(T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following (unnecessary) brackets will explain how it's getting evaluated:

```
print((not (8 < 4)) or ((10 == 5 * 2) and not (5 > 3)))
```

Since `(not (8 < 4))` is evaluated to `True` (the other side of the `or` doesn't matter) this is the returned result